# After patching our SharePoint 2013 using March 2022, we got this weired farm build number 15.0.5429.1000 instead of 15.0.5431.1000

Tags: 2013, administration, patching, configuration-wizard

We successfully patch our SharePoint 2013 using March 2022 ans we successfully run the product configuration wizard. But we got this weird farm build number **15.0.5429.1000** (when we run the below power shell command), instead of **15.0.5431.1000** as per this link https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346#SP2013.

```
 $farm = Get-SPFarm
 $farm.BuildVersion
```

so is our farm corrupted with this **15.0.5429.1000** build number? and why we got this number instead of **15.0.5431.1000**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Patch build numbers do not always match farm build numbers. This is a normal, semi-regular occurrence with SharePoint Server patches.